# Could not establish a secure connection to server with safari

Tags: ssl, safari

Sorry for cross posting, but I wasnt sure whether to post here, or on serverfault.

Safari tells me that it couldnt open the page, because it couldnt establish a secure connection to the server. However, other browsers (opera, firefox) can open the page. Also, theres nothing in the apache error log.

The certificate is selfsigned, and uses standart values. (seen here: http://www.knaupes.net/tutorial-ssl-zertifikat-selbst-erstellen-und-signieren/ )

ssl config:

```
SSLEngine on
#SSLInsecureRenegotiation on 
SSLCertificateFile /home/gemeinde/certs/selfsigned/gemeinde.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/gemeinde/certs/selfsigned/gemeinde.key
#SSLCACertificateFile /home/gemeinde/certs/Platinum_G2.pem
#SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

<Location "/">
     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +OptRenegotiate
     SSLVerifyClient optional
     SSLVerifyDepth 10
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try SSLInsecureRenegotiation on

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue , it got resolved when I unchecked the Web Proxy and Secure Web Proxy from System Preferences